# How to update Listboxitems when ObservableCollection Changes

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I have a Listbox display an ObservableCollection (OC). The items in this listbox can be a few different user controls which is dependend on a specific object in the OC (this is handled by a type to view converter).

In each UserControl I am displaying the current OC index (as a string) using an IndexConverter. This all works great.

**My problem:** whenever I perform changes to the OC (add, remove, etc ) the index on the listboxitems themselves are not updating.

**My question:** what is the best way (in MVVM) to invoke the listboxitems to update once the OC changes?

*Code snipped of the ListBox:*

```
<!-- Measurement list -->
        <ListBox x:Name="MeasurementViewList" ItemsSource="{Binding MeasurementViewList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMeasurementItem, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource Type2ViewConv}}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>


                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

*Code in an UserControl:*

```
<!-- Measurement list index -->
        <TextBlock x:Name="measurementListIndex" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                                AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Mode=OneWay, 
                                Converter={StaticResource IndexConv}}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="12" Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  />
```

Comment: In case you are asking about the current index of an item in the ItemsSource collection, you may want to take a look at the ListBox's AlternationIndex and AlternationCount properties. Besides that, it seems odd to have a "type to view" converter. There is already built-in automatic DataTemplate selection (by means of a DataTemplate's DataType property), and beyond that, also the ListBox's ItemTemplateSelector.

Comment: Be careful with using names [WPF memory leak when using x:Name](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2014/09/04/fighting-common-wpf-memory-leaks-with-dotmemory/)

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it is by having ViewModels as the items of the `ObservableCollection`, add an `Index` property on that ViewModel, and update that property for each item whenever I manipulate (add, remove, move, etc.) the `ObservableCollection`.

I would adjust the `DataTemplate` to use a `ContentControl` with both the `Content` (to forward the VM as the `DataContext`) and `ContentTemplateSelector` (to replace the `Type2ViewConv`) properties.

```xml
<DataTemplate>
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"
                      ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource SomeTemplateSelector}"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
 </DataTemplate>
```

With that in place, each `UserControl` would have the item's ViewModel as its `DataContext`, which would allow binding to the `Index` property.

```xml
<!-- Within the UserControls, you can display the index with this. -->
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Index}" />
```